# Laravel 5 sharing data to all views from repositories (avoid duplicate queries)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a layout which includes a lot of modal windows, which are accessible on each page. Each of this modal needs some data. For example, I have a modal with task creation form which needs task types. On the other hand the task creation form may be included in some pages of my site. It means that on some pages there are 2 or more same forms. All of them need the same data.

I've read about `view()->share` method. The problem is that I got quite a lot of stuff to share which I get from repositories. I have a service provider for view composers, and there I've tried to inject repositories and pass data to view share, but apparently it doesn't work, I got 500 error without any logs at all.

So, in a nutshell, how can I get task types from task repository and pass to all views? Right now I have `\View::composer('private.*', 'CRM\ViewComposers\SharedDataViewComposer');` but in case there are 2 or more forms included into one view the data is duplicated, because view composer supply 2 views with the same data.

Answer (score 0):

you can pass to the app provider boot() method the array of views you need the data in and than, only in this views the data will be available. so for instance, if you have a view that includes 3 other views, you can put in this array the name of the views you need and it'll ignore the rest.

for example:

```
protected $viewsList = array('view1', 'view2', 'view3');    

public function boot()
{   

    view()->composer($viewsList, function($view){

        $extraInfo = 'the data you need';

        $view->with("extra_info", $extraInfo);
    });
}
```

Than, in your view just use this data:

```
@if(isset($extra_info))
      <p>{{ $extra_info }}</p>
@endif
```

Comment: But if all the views are included in one view, I'll get 3 duplicated queries?